# Does a URL that redirects to some other URL always contain the string '=http'?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-redirect, redirect

I am trying to determine the final location of a given URL, using Java / HttpURLConnection.

The code is pretty simple, taking String 'ref' as input and returning a URL string as output:

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(ref).openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","");
        if (con.getResponseCode()/100 == 3)
        {
            String target = con.getHeaderField("Location");
            if (target != null)
                return target;
        }
        return con.getURL().toString();
```

The problem is that in certain cases, the result I get contains yet another redirection.

This happens not only when the response code is 3xx, but also when it is 2xx.

I need some sort of deterministic way for deciding whether or not I should send the output as input to the same method (above).

Can I safely assume that the result contains a redirection IF AND ONLY IF it contains the string '=http'?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify the question above:

It's not "my" server, it can be any server "out there" that I'm connecting to through HTTP.

I have had several problems finding the landing-page of a URL that contains a redirection:

1. Sometimes the response code is 3xx, but the location header is null.
2. Sometimes the response code is 3xx, and the location header contains a valid URL:

   - Sometimes this URL is "final".
   - Sometimes this URL contains yet another redirection.
3. Sometimes the response code is 2xx, but the URL contains yet another redirection.

The code above is what I found to be the simplest way to get to the landing-page of a given URL, yet, in some rare cases I still get a URL that contains another redirection.

Comment: 3xx codes don't always cause a redirection. Just keep following the redirection. Also, HTTP clients like Apache's HttpComponents can do all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but the [`Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) header is used as follows

> For 201 (Created) responses, the Location is that of the new resource
>   which was created by the request. For 3xx responses, the location
>   SHOULD indicate the server's preferred URI for automatic redirection
>   to the resource. The field value consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> `Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI`

If your server is not behaving this way, then it's not behaving the standard HTTP way and you, as a client, will need some out of band information to use it.

Comment: Agree. Check out the Wikipedia article on HTTP location - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location - if the response has a 'Location' header, then you have redirection.